# Is there a way to write a middleware to all hasura queries and mutations?

Tags: hasura

I want to add a custom logging system to my app where I can log all the actions performed by a user and record them in a separate table. For this, I need to write a middleware to all existing and future hasura queries and mutations. Will this be possible? Is there a way to add a middleware like in an express app?

Comment: You can turn on `query-log` on hasura and collect everything that goes in hasura. I suppose no need for additional middleware for this. Look at: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/deployment/logging.html#query-log-structure

Answer (score 0):

Hasura afaik does not provide any such feature apart from actions but from your requirements it seems that you are looking for an auditing system which is more of a database thing then hasura one. Hasura docs do provide some information on it [here](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/guides/auditing-tables.html) and see the sample code [here](https://github.com/hasura/audit-trigger)